# How to echo a value out from a button?

Tags: php

I have a page that have a button like this,
[image]

When this button is clicked, a pop out modal will show,
[image]

Once the submit button is clicked, a small note will show up,
[image]

Below are my codes,

```
<div class="col-md-12" role="main">
                        <div class="bs-docs-section">
                            <h1 class="page-header">Today's Activity  <button class="btn btn-primary">Add new</button></h1>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        $con = getDbConnect();
                        $day = date("l");

                        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                            "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        } else {
                            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM timetableschedule  WHERE staffID= '" . $staff_information["staff_Id"] . "' AND day='" . $day . "' ");

                            while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" schedule="
                                    <?php
                                    echo "<br/>";
                                    echo $schedule['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
                                    echo $schedule['startTime'] . "-" . $schedule['endTime'] . "hrs<br />";
                                    echo "<br/>";
                                    ?>">
                                            <?php
                                                echo "<br/>";
                                                echo $schedule['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
                                                echo $schedule['startTime'] . "-" . $schedule['endTime'] . "hrs<br />";
                                                echo "<br/>";
                                                ?>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">

                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Insert Today's Activity</h4>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p class="activity"></p>
                                                <p>Click on the submit button if the above infomation is correct.</p>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-ok SUB" >Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                        $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('schedule', $(e.relatedTarget).attr('schedule'));

                                        $('.activity').html('You have selected: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('schedule') + '</strong>');

                                    });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".SUB").click(clickSUB);
        })
        function clickSUB(){
            $("#processSUB").load("hello.php");
        }
                                </script>
                                <div id="processSUB"></div>   
                                <?php
                            }
                            mysqli_close($con);
                        }
                        ?>

                    </div>
```

My codes for the hello.php,

```html
<?php
echo 'You have submitted';
echo $schedule['timetableId'];
?>
```

Is there a way to get the 'timetableId' from the button?

Comment: get it from what button, when?  There is like 5-6 buttons there, `mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM timetableschedule  WHERE staffID= '" . $staff_information["staff_Id"] .` = bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 2nd Parameter of [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)() to pass data as parameter, you can pass `timetableId` or any other parameter required.

```
load('hello.php', { timetableId : javascriptVarWithValue });
```

you will receive passed data in `$_POST` in hello.php

In hello.php you can access like:

```
<?php echo $_POST['timetableId']; ?>
```

---

In loop, load the `timetableId` something like:

```
<div id="tableID" data-timetable-id="<?php $schedule['timetableId']; ?>" style="display: none;"></div>
```

In `clickSUB()` fetch the value something like this:

```
function clickSUB(){
    // changed to data('timetableId') instead of data('timeTableId')
    var timeTableId = $('#tableID').data('timetableId');
    console.log(timeTableId); 
    $("#processSUB").load("hello.php", { timetableID : timeTableId });
}
```

Comment: How should i write the javascript?

Comment: @Raymond actually I can't see `timetableId` in your code, just in hello.php where you are just displaying. May be you want to fetch the value from database first and display it in HTML DOM.

Comment: timetableId is from the database table 'timetableschedule'

Comment: @Raymond check updated answer, notice the comment and console.log for debugging. and I am assuming `$schedule['timetableId']` is correctly populated.